# Prevent NSIS from appending archive?

Tags: nsis, virus

I had bad day when a virus infect all *.exe including many of my NSIS installer and stripping them to only the stub (+ the virus code).

I wonder if there an option to pack archive inside the stub instead? So at least if it got infected the whole archive (hence the installer exe) could ve recovered by AV

This also mean if the file been tampered it will invalidated the PE too. So no /NCRC then

Answer (score 0):

Even if the compressed data was stored in a PE section or resource, a virus could still strip it out when infecting. While the chance of data survival is probably better than the current implementation it will also complicate the compilation phase for makensis.

It is open source and you are free to submit a patch :)

Comment: yeah, don't think about the compilation though. I will consider msi then despite its horrible compression